# Pandas Groupby with bad rows

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to force pandas.groupby to return a DataFrame? Here's an example illustrating my problem:

The toy dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(a=[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 
                            b=[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4])
```

This function returns a dataframe as expected:

```
def fcn_good(d):
    return pd.Series(data=dict(mean=d.b.mean(), std=d.b.std()))
print(df.groupby('a').apply(fcn_good))
```

With output

```
   mean  std
a
1   1.0  0.0
2   2.0  0.0
3   4.0  0.0
```

Now here is the problem. In my real code, some of the groupby keys will fail during the calculation. The output I want is:

```
   mean  std
a
1   1.0  0.0
2   NaN  NaN
3   4.0  0.0
```

However, this code

```
def fcn_bad(d):
    if int(d.a.unique()[0]) == 2: # Simulate failure
        return pd.Series()
    return pd.Series(data=dict(mean=d.b.mean(), std=d.b.std()))
print(df.groupby('a').apply(fcn_bad))
```

Returns a series instead:

```
a
1  mean    1.0
   std     0.0
3  mean    4.0
   std     0.0
dtype: float64
```

Anyone know how to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) values of column `a`, because [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) is by column `a`:

```
def fcn_bad(d):
    if int(d.a.unique()[0]) == 2: # Simulate failure
        return pd.Series()
    return pd.Series(data=dict(mean=d.b.mean(), std=d.b.std()))
print(df.groupby('a').apply(fcn_bad).unstack().reindex(df.a.unique()))
   mean  std
a           
1   1.0  0.0
2   NaN  NaN
3   4.0  0.0
```

---

If add `index` with column names of final `df` to `Series` like `pd.Series(index=['mean','std'])`, it return `DataFrame`:

```
def fcn_bad(d):
    if int(d.a.unique()[0]) == 2: # Simulate failure
        return pd.Series(index=['mean','std'])
    return pd.Series(data=dict(mean=d.b.mean(), std=d.b.std()))
print(df.groupby('a').apply(fcn_bad))
   mean  std
a           
1   1.0  0.0
2   NaN  NaN
3   4.0  0.0
```